# How can I keep a list of View structs in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, swift5

Since SwiftUI's `NavigationView` is extremely rigid and does not provide an easy way for programatic navigation, I wanted to create an `AppNavigationView` that has an array of views and updates its rendered view based on push/pop.

Because a SwiftUI view is a protocol with an associatedType, I cannot either create an array of Views or even pass a few in my `public func pushView(view:View)`.

So how can I store a list of View structs?

```
// Error: Protocol 'View' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements.
@State var navigationStack: [View]
```

Comment: Note that even if you make it compile, this goes against all SwiftUI patterns, and will likely not work for you as expected. Store data, not views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift does not allow to use protocol as member type, so most close would be to use

```
@State private var navigationStack: [AnyView]

//...

public func pushView<V:View>(view: V) {
   navigationStack.append(AnyView(view))
}
```